# How am I misusing javax.swing.Timer?

Tags: java, swing, timer

Here I created a game where you roll a dice and draw a bug one part at a time . Here's the
list of what rolls get you what parts and how many you need.

- 1 - body (need one)
- 2 - head (need one; must have a body first)
- 3 - eyes (need two, must have a head first)
- 4 - antenna (need two; must have head first )
- 5 - legs (need six; must have body first)
- 6 - tail (need one; must have body first)

You have to click on the screen near where the body part goes to make it show up. Then we
could time the whole thing.

I used the Panel to work with my timer, but I am not getting what is wrong?

Main Program

```
package dice;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Yahtzee extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
  Die[] d; // array to hold the 5 dice
  FourOfAKind[] f;
  JPanel buttonPanel; // panel for the timer
  JPanel dicePanel; // panel to hold the dice
  JPanel bugPanel;
  ScoreRow[] theScores;

  protected Object bug;

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    Yahtzee y = new Yahtzee();
   }

    public Yahtzee() 
    {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    dicePanel = new JPanel();
    dicePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
    dicePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    dicePanel.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

    add(dicePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    d = new Die[1];
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
        d[i] = new Die(this);
        dicePanel.add(d[i]);
    }

    bugPanel = new JPanel();
    bugPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));
    bugPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    bugPanel.setSize(new Dimension(50, 50));

    add(bugPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    f = new FourOfAKind[1];
    for (int w = 0; w < 1; w++) {
        f[w] = new FourOfAKind(this);
        bugPanel.add(f[w]);
    }
    setSize(new Dimension(715, 705));
    setVisible(true);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    repaint();

}

public void setChoice(int choice) 
{
    f[0].setChoice(choice);
}

public void drawBug() 
{
    f[0].setChoice(d[0].getChoice());
    f[0].drawBug();
}

    }
```

I commented out the timer stuff that are not compiling.

Comment: What is the problem? What behavior do you expect? What happens instead?

Comment: Im expecting after I finish drawing my bug i would click on the panel and stop the timer and see how long it toke me to draw the bug.

Comment: you can't start a timer, then build a new timer object, then stop that timer. you're replacing your `timer` object with a new one...

Comment: Oh ok so how would that work, if you dont mind showing me?

Answer (score 2):

> "Im expecting after I finish drawing my bug i would click on the panel and stop the timer and see how long it toke me to draw the bug."

You don't need a `Timer` *at all*. If you're not updating anything in your UI, than you don't need it.

You can keep track of time other ways. One way is whenever you want to start the keeping track of time, just use `System.currentTimeMiilis()`. Have a global variable `long startTime` and set it when you want the clock to start

```
long startTime;
...
startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

When you want to stop the clock just do it again and subtract the difference

```
long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
long elapsedMillis = endTime - startTime;
long elapsedSeconds = elapsedMillis / 1000;
```

Comment: Oh, and under what methods im I supposed to put it under?

Comment: Who the heck knows. You're the only one who knows how your program is supposed to work.

Comment: When you start painting, set the start time. When you stop, get the end time. That simple. If you can't understand that, then you don't understand your _own_ program, if it is even _yours_

Comment: Excuse me what do you mean by if it even yours?

Comment: Maybe that was out of line. But understand the frustration. First your question in unclear as it is. Second my explanation is pretty straight forward of how to keep track of time. Third, since your question is so unclear, no one know where to put that code but _you_

Comment: I mean ask me questions I really dont know what im unclear about?

Comment: What in your code is supposed to start the timer. If you don't know, how are we supposed to know? And also what in your code is supposed to stop it? If you can't answer those two questions based off your own code, then How do you expect us to guess? If you can answer those two questions, then we can start there.

Comment: @user3412136 Even if we knew your code inside-out, what constitutes the time taken to form a bug is arbitrary. It should be trivial to determine when you want to start and end. You wrote the code, and only **you** can provide this information.